# OpenGL is using the last texture loaded

Tags: c++, opengl

Edit:
Ive narrowed it down to this:  It seems like if I do the below in my function, and then in the renderer function never call glBindTexture again it will still render... the textures...

```
NM->data = stbi_load ( FileBuf  , &NM->width , &NM->height , &NM->bit , 0 );
//glGenTextures ( 1 , &NM->texture [ 0 ] );                                 // ** OFF **
//glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, NM->texture [ 0 ] );                       // ** OFF **
//glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_LINEAR );    // ** Enableing This Will Render White (no texture)
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GL_LINEAR );      // ** Enableing This Will Render the texture for both objects *** SUPER WEIRD ***
// *** ALSO *** I dont ever call glBindTexture Again after this but still the object is being textured ***
glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , GL_RGBA , NM->width , NM->width , 0 , GL_RGBA , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , NM->data );
stbi_image_free ( NM->data );
```

### I must not be understanding something, or I have a big error in my code.

---

I am just trying to get WaveFront objects with materials loaded, and rendered.  With that said, Im just trying to piece together some code to get a better understanding of how everything works so I can go back and reprogram everything.  (I am on windows)

I can load .objects from files and even load textures... Problem is, the last texture loaded is used for all objects....

here it glIntercept for loading the images...

```
glGenTextures(1,05331C10)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,1024,1024,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,05733040)
glGenTextures(1,05332780)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,2)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST)
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,1024,1024,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0573D040)
```

.. From:

```
NM->MapUsed = true;
sscanf ( coord [ i ]->c_str() , "map_Kd %s" , NM->map_Kd );
char FileBuf [ 256 ] = { 0x0 };
sprintf ( FileBuf , "C:\\OpenGL\\Debug\\%s" , NM->map_Kd );
NM->data = stbi_load ( FileBuf  , &NM->width , &NM->height , &NM->bit , 0 );
glGenTextures ( 1 , &NM->texture );
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, NM->texture );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GL_NEAREST );
glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , GL_RGBA , NM->width , NM->height , 0 , GL_RGBA , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , NM->data );
stbi_image_free ( NM->data );
```

The above code is how I am loading the texture.  NM is in a vector array in VectorMaterialLibrary, and that is in ObjectLoader vector...

```
void Renderer() {

    updatecam();

    // all My Objects
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < ObjectLoader.size() ; i++ ) {
        sObjectLoader *TempObject = ObjectLoader [ i ];

        if ( TempObject->MTLFile ) {
            for ( int z = 0 ; z < TempObject->VectorMaterialLibrary.size() ; z++ ) {
                sMaterialLibrary *TempMaterial = TempObject->VectorMaterialLibrary [ z ];
                if ( strcmp ( TempMaterial->newmtl , TempObject->usemtl ) == 0 ) {
                    if ( TempMaterial->MapUsed ) {
                        glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, TempMaterial->texture );  // *** This Dings 1/2 respectively ***
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for ( int z = 0 ; z < TempObject->_3f.size() ; z++ ) {
            s3f *Temp3f = TempObject->_3f [ z ];
            if ( Temp3f->GL_TYPE == GL_QUADS ) {
                glBegin ( GL_QUADS );
                if ( Temp3f->boolvn ) {
                    glNormal3f ( Temp3f->vn [ 0 ] , Temp3f->vn [ 1 ] , Temp3f->vn [ 2 ] );
                }
                if ( Temp3f->boolv ) {
                    if ( Temp3f->boolvt ) glTexCoord2f ( Temp3f->vt [ 0 ] , Temp3f->vt [ 1 ] );
                    glVertex3f ( Temp3f->v [ 0 ] , Temp3f->v [ 1 ] , Temp3f->v [ 2 ] );

                    if ( Temp3f->boolvt ) glTexCoord2f ( Temp3f->vt [ 2 ] , Temp3f->vt [ 3 ] );
                    glVertex3f ( Temp3f->v [ 3 ] , Temp3f->v [ 4 ] , Temp3f->v [ 5 ] );

                    if ( Temp3f->boolvt ) glTexCoord2f ( Temp3f->vt [ 4 ] , Temp3f->vt [ 5 ] );
                    glVertex3f ( Temp3f->v [ 6 ] , Temp3f->v [ 7 ] , Temp3f->v [ 8 ] );

                    if ( Temp3f->boolvt ) glTexCoord2f ( Temp3f->vt [ 6 ] , Temp3f->vt [ 7 ] );
                    glVertex3f ( Temp3f->v [ 9 ] , Temp3f->v [ 10 ] , Temp3f->v [ 11 ] );
                }
                glEnd();
            } else {
                glBegin ( GL_TRIANGLES );
                if ( Temp3f->boolvn ) {
                    glNormal3f ( Temp3f->vn [ 0 ] , Temp3f->vn [ 1 ] , Temp3f->vn [ 2 ] );
                }
                if ( Temp3f->boolv ) {
                    if ( Temp3f->boolvt ) glTexCoord2f ( Temp3f->vt [ 0 ] , Temp3f->vt [ 1 ] );
                    glVertex3f ( Temp3f->v [ 0 ] , Temp3f->v [ 1 ] , Temp3f->v [ 2 ] );

                    if ( Temp3f->boolvt ) glTexCoord2f ( Temp3f->vt [ 2 ] , Temp3f->vt [ 3 ] );
                    glVertex3f ( Temp3f->v [ 3 ] , Temp3f->v [ 4 ] , Temp3f->v [ 5 ] );

                    if ( Temp3f->boolvt ) glTexCoord2f ( Temp3f->vt [ 4 ] , Temp3f->vt [ 5 ] );
                    glVertex3f ( Temp3f->v [ 6 ] , Temp3f->v [ 7 ] , Temp3f->v [ 8 ] );
                }
                glEnd();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Also, the glintercept for the render (took the last image1 call and the start of image2...)

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES) Textures[ (0,1) ] 
glNormal3f(0.000000,0.000000,-1.000000)
glTexCoord2f(1.000000,0.000000)
glVertex3f(1.892851,-0.950534,-3.331728)
glTexCoord2f(1.000000,1.000000)
glVertex3f(-0.107149,-0.950534,-3.331728)
glTexCoord2f(0.000000,1.000000)
glVertex3f(-0.107149,1.049466,-3.331728)
glEnd()
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,2)
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES) Textures[ (0,2) ] 
glNormal3f(0.000000,-1.000000,-0.000000)
glTexCoord2f(0.000000,0.000000)
glVertex3f(1.892851,-0.950534,-3.331728)
glTexCoord2f(1.000000,0.000000)
glVertex3f(1.892851,-0.950534,-1.331729)
glTexCoord2f(0.000000,1.000000)
glVertex3f(-0.107149,-0.950534,-3.331728)
glEnd()
```

Im wondering where I went wrong.  I really just want this to work so I can recode the framework from scratch again.

If you need further code, I can post it, but I dont want a big wall!!!

// Edit, manually doing the following.. *bad*

```
// I only have 2 objects with this test, and 2 materials...
                if ( testing ) {
                    glGenTextures ( 2 , Gtextures );    // ********Global
                    testing = false;
                    NM->data = stbi_load ( FileBuf  , &NM->width , &NM->height , &NM->bit , 0 );
                    glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gtextures[0] );
                    glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_NEAREST );
                    glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GL_NEAREST );
                    glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , GL_RGBA , NM->width , NM->height , 0 , GL_RGBA , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , NM->data );
                    stbi_image_free ( NM->data );
                } else {
                    NM->data = stbi_load ( FileBuf  , &NM->width , &NM->height , &NM->bit , 0 );
                    glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gtextures[1] );
                    glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER , GL_NEAREST );
                    glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER , GL_NEAREST );
                    glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D , 0 , GL_RGBA , NM->width , NM->height , 0 , GL_RGBA , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , NM->data );
                    stbi_image_free ( NM->data );
                }
```

**

```
for ( int z = 0 ; z < TempObject->VectorMaterialLibrary.size() ; z++ ) {
                sMaterialLibrary *TempMaterial = TempObject->VectorMaterialLibrary [ z ];
                if ( strcmp ( TempMaterial->newmtl , TempObject->usemtl ) == 0 ) {
                    if ( TempMaterial->MapUsed ) {
                        //mbci ( "Changing Texture" , i );
                        //mbci ( "Gtextures [ i ]" , Gtextures [ i ] );
                        glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, Gtextures [ i ] );  // ** I only have 2 objects so this works for loading the 2 textures...
                        //glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, TempMaterial->texture );
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

But the object is STILL the same texture...

Here is a picture of something I am rendering.  Notice everything is the same color...  The two cubes in the middle should be two different colors, and the other objects are also taking the same texture...  here are the two textures (scaled down ofc)

```
What I See https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1NXn.png ** No Idea **
Cube UV1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/s44Tb.png ** This is loaded first**
Cube UV2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KXdo.png ** This is loaded last **
```

Comment: Are you changing the texture before the first glBegin draw call ?

Comment: @concept3d Yes, I placed some messagebox's in there to check.  Hm.

Comment: You also need to make sure you are not uploading the same texture multiple times. GLdebugger have a nice OpenGL debugging features. its free.

Comment: @concept3d I checked that too with a messagebox for the FileBuf.  Both are loaded once.  That loading function is only called one time when it is parsing the .obj file.  Ill download the app!  Thank you.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you learn the deprecated fixed function pipeline. If not then you avoid to learn the old deprecated way of working with opengl.

Comment: @user3214406: Why are you using message boxes? Just `fprintf(stderr,…)` to the console.

Comment: @datenwolf Because I am not using glut or anything else if that is what you are wondering.  Right?

Comment: @user3214406: That doesn't prevent you from using stdio. You can always start your program from a console and if you run your program from Visual Studio its output will end up in console log as well. stdio is much better suited for debugging, because it doesn't require you to become interactive. If you want interactive debugging, use debugger breakpoints.

Comment: If this is still not solved, you can check this out: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=770639&seqNum=5 - However, just like t.niese, I would not recommend to use legacy OpenGL in new code. If you used GLSL, this question would have been answered in minutes. ;)

Comment: @thokra I have that book!  Although, I looked through the texturing chapter (8), but I still cant figure out what I am doing wrong...  This is bugging me.  Also, "glActiveTexture" does not seem to be in the API?  I am going to see if I can just build a very very basic example and get it working...

Answer (score 3):

I hate to do this, but after a couple days debugging and going over my OpenGL booklets I have answered my own question.

The problem with my code was based on the .obj format and how I am ordering the faces.  In .obj format each .obj is incremented... example:

**OBJECT ONE**

```
f 5/1/1 6/2/1 1/3/1
f 6/1/2 7/2/2 2/3/2
f 7/1/3 8/2/3 3/3/3
f 8/1/4 5/2/4 4/3/4
f 1/1/5 2/2/5 4/3/5
f 8/1/6 7/2/6 5/3/6
f 6/2/1 2/4/1 1/3/1
f 7/2/2 3/4/2 2/3/2
f 8/2/3 4/4/3 3/3/3
f 5/2/4 1/4/4 4/3/4
f 2/2/5 3/4/5 4/3/5
f 7/2/6 6/4/6 5/3/6
```

**OBJECT TWO**

```
f 9/5/7 10/6/7 12/7/7
f 13/5/8 16/6/8 14/7/8
f 9/5/9 13/6/9 10/7/9
f 10/5/10 14/6/10 11/7/10
f 11/5/11 15/6/11 12/7/11
f 13/5/12 9/6/12 16/7/12
f 10/6/7 11/8/7 12/7/7
f 16/6/8 15/8/8 14/7/8
f 13/6/13 14/8/13 10/7/13
f 14/6/10 15/8/10 11/7/10
f 15/6/11 16/8/11 12/7/11
f 9/6/12 12/8/12 16/7/12
```

How I was storing the Vertex/VertexTexture/VertexNormals, were correct, **but my loop was starting from 0 on the second object, meaning I was actually recreating the first objects all over again, thus it applied the last texture...**

To anyone else: Please be aware of how your program is storing and reading things.

A couple days of work with only a single line of code changed to make it functional... yippie.

It would be nice if there were a way to make sure blender did not do this...